# Reduce by column max in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Imagine that I have the following array:

```
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[3,3]])
```

I want to halve its length by taking pairs of elements and discarding the one with the lower sum of values. This is easy in one dimensions where no sum is necessary:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a.reshape((-1,2)).max(axis=1)
```

And yields the desired result: `[2,4]`

My question, is it possible to do the equivalent in two dimensions such that the operation on `b` yields `[[3,4],[5,6]]`?

For reference, here is a non-numpy way of doing this:

```
b = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[3,3]]
c = []
for i in range(0,len(b) - 1,2):
    if sum(b[i]) > sum(b[i+1]):
        c += [b[i]]
    else:
        c += [b[i+1]]
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the sums, take the `argmax` and apply that to the original pairs:

```
# form pairs of pairs
>>> b2 = b.reshape(*b.shape[:-2], -1, 2, b.shape[-1])
# sum and take the argmax for each pair of sums
>>> idx = np.argmax(b2.sum(axis=-1), axis=-1)
# use the argmax to select the relevant pairs
>>> c = b2[np.arange(b2.shape[0]), idx]
# admire
>>> c
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: `# admire` indeed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using splices, `zip()`, and `map()`:

```
map(lambda x: x[0] if sum(x[0]) > sum(x[1]) else x[1], zip(b[::2], b[1::2]))
#[array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
```

**Explanation**

- `b[::2]` gets every other element in `b` starting from index 0.
- `b[1::2]` gets every other element in `b` starting from index 1.
- `zip(b[::2], b[1::2])` creates a list of pairwise tuples from `b`.
- `map(lambda x: x[0] if sum(x[0]) > sum(x[1]) else x[1])` returns the element from each tuple with the highest sum.

If you wanted the output as a `list` of lists as you showed in the example, simply wrap the output of the `map()` step with the `list()` constructor:

```
map(
    lambda x: list(x[0]) if sum(x[0]) > sum(x[1]) else list(x[1]),
    zip(b[::2], b[1::2])
)
#[[3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 3]])

ibl = len(b)

'''
Using this method you will get half max elements for even number of 
array elements and (half-1)/2 for odd number of array elements. And 
it will work for any array/subarray size
'''
while len(b) > int(ibl/2) :
    b = np.array(list([bb for bb in b if any(sum(bb) > sum(other) for other in b)]))


output: array([[3, 4],
   [5, 6]])
```